# Relating the normal sheaf of $S \subset \operatorname{Sym}^2(S)$ to $\Omega_S$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, quotient-spaces, invariant-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
Let $S$  be a smooth variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, $\operatorname{char}k \neq 2$, and let $\Sym^2(S) = (S \times_k S) / (\mathbb Z/2)$ be the second symmetric power of $S$. Then $S$ embeds diagonally as a closed subscheme into $\Sym^2(S)$,
$$\delta: S \to \Sym^2(S).$$
Clearly $\delta$ is the composition of the ordinary diagonal $\Delta: S \to S \times S$ with the quotient map $p: S \times S \to \Sym^2(S)$.

I would like to understand the conormal sheaf $\mathcal C_{S / \Sym^2(S)} = I_\delta / I_\delta^2$. My first suspicion that $$p^* I_\delta = I_\Delta^2$$
is actually not correct, since the group quotient is not flat.

See my answer below, I was still able to show
$$\mathcal C_{S / \Sym^2(S)} = \delta^* I_\delta = \Delta^* p^* I_\delta = \Delta^* I_\Delta^2 = I_\Delta^2 / I_\Delta^3.$$

Comment: It should be enough to compute the conormal sheaf to $\mathbb{A}^n / \{\pm 1\}$ at the origin.

Comment: @Sasha I know that calculation, and how it can be applied to solve the case $S = \mathbb A^n$, by an appropriate coordinate change. But I don't clearly see how to lift/generalize this for other cases of $S$. By some kind of completion argument?

Comment: Every smooth variety is etale locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$, and your question is etale local.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks that was helpful, I think I worked out the details :)

Comment: Note that $I_\Delta^2/I_\Delta^3\simeq{\rm Sym}^2(\Omega_S)$ because the closed immersion $\Delta$ is regular.

Comment: @DamianRössler Yep, that is why I wanted to understand the whole thing at all :) For a surface $S$ I'm looking at the blow-up of $\operatorname{Sym}^2(S)$ along the diagonal, $\operatorname{Hilb}^2(S) \to \operatorname{Sym}^2(S)$, and wanted to understand the exceptional divisor $D \to S$, which turns out to be $\mathbb P(\Omega_S)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $p^{-1}(\delta(S)) \subset \Delta(S)$, we have a morphism of sheaves
$$p^* I_\delta \to I_\Delta \subset \mathcal O_{S \times S}.$$
*Claim.* This morphism gives a surjection $p^* I_\delta \twoheadrightarrow I_\Delta^2$, which becomes an isomorphism $\delta^* I_\delta \cong I_\Delta^2 / I_\Delta^3$ after pulling-back via $\Delta$.

*Proof*. We first deal with the case $S = \mathbb A^n = \operatorname{Spec}(k[s_1, \dotsc, s_n])$, where this can be done by explicit calculation.
On $S \times S$ we have then coordinates $s_1, \dotsc, s_n, t_1, \dotsc, t_n$ and the $\mathbb Z/2$-action is $\sigma(s_i) = t_i$. Introducting new coordinates
$$x_i = \frac 1 2 (s_i + t_i) \quad \text{and} \quad \xi_i = \frac 1 2 (s_i - t_i)$$
we see that the subring of invariants is
$$R^{\mathbb Z /2} = k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n, \xi_1^2, \xi_1 \xi_2, \dotsc, \xi_1 \xi_n, \xi_2^2, \xi_2 \xi_3, \dotsc] \subset k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n, \xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_n] = R.$$
Then $I_\Delta = (\xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_n) \subset R$, and $I_\delta = (\xi_i \cdot \xi_j \,|\, i,j= 1, \dotsc, n) \subset R^{\mathbb Z/2}$. So $I_\delta$ generates the ideal $I_\Delta^2$ over $R$, which means we have the surjection $I_\delta \otimes R \twoheadrightarrow I_\Delta^2$.
Note that this is not injective (the  group quotient is not flat). For example elements of type $\xi_i \xi_j \otimes \xi_k - \xi_j \xi_k \otimes \xi_i$ are in the kernel. However, if we mod out $(\xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_n)$ this becomes injective: The kernel of the composite map $I_\delta \otimes R \to I_\Delta^2 \to I_\Delta^2 / I_\Delta^3$ is exactly $$I_\delta \otimes I_\Delta \subset I_\delta \otimes R,$$
which is mapped to zero under the quotient $I_\delta \otimes R \to I_\delta \otimes R/I_\Delta$. So we obtain an isomorphism
$$\delta^* I_\delta = I_\delta \otimes R/I_\Delta \cong I_\Delta^2 / I_\Delta ^3.$$
Now to the general case. As the map $p^*I_\delta \to I_\Delta$ is defined globally, it is sufficient to check the claim on a Zariski cover. By [Stacks 054L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/054L) we may assume that $S$ is affine, and admits an étale morphism $f: S \to \mathbb A^n$. Then $f$ induces morphisms $S \times S \to \mathbb A^n \times \mathbb A^n$ and $\operatorname{Sym}^2(S) \to \operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb A^n)$, leading to a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S \times S @>f \times f>\text{étale}> \mathbb A^n \times \mathbb A^n\\
@VpVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Sym}^2(S) @>{}>> \operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb A^n) \\
@AAA @AAA \\
S @>{\text{étale}}>f> \mathbb A^n
\end{CD}$$
Note however, that the middle horizontal arrow is in general *not* étale. If you have two points $s \neq t \in S$ with $f(s) = f(t)$, the corresponding point $[s+t] \in \operatorname{Sym}^2(S)$ is a smooth point. But it maps to the singular point $[2f(s)] \in \operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb A^n)$.

Since $f \times f$ is étale, the preimage of $\Delta(\mathbb A^n)$ decomposes as a disjoint union $(f \times f)^{-1}(\Delta(\mathbb A^n)) = \Delta(S) \sqcup Z$, and $\operatorname{Sym}^2(S) \setminus p(Z)$ is an open neighbourhood of $\delta(S)$, mapping étale to $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb A^n)$. So the following diagrams are cartesian, all horizontal morphisms étale:
$$
\begin{CD}
S @>f>> \mathbb A^n @. S @>f>> \mathbb A^n\\
@V\delta_SVV @VV\delta_{\mathbb A^n}V @VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Sym}^2(S) \setminus p(Z) @>>g> \operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb A^n) @. S \times S \setminus Z @>>> \mathbb A^n \times \mathbb A^n
\end{CD}$$
From this and the flatness of $g$ we obtain $$\delta_S^* I_{\delta_S} = \delta_S^* g^* I_{\delta_{\mathbb A^n}} = f^* \delta_{\mathbb A^n}^* I_{\delta_{\mathbb A^n}} = f^* I_{\Delta_{\mathbb A^n}}^2 / I_{\Delta_{\mathbb A^n}}^3 = I_{\Delta_S}^2 / I_{\Delta_S}^3.$$